# Timber / TWIG spearate Templates for specific Categories

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, categories, timber

So in the starter theme we have this:

**archive.php:**

```
$templates = array( 'archive.twig', 'index.twig' );

$context = Timber::get_context();

$context['title'] = 'Archive';
if ( is_day() ) {
    $context['title'] = 'Archive: ' . get_the_date( 'D M Y' );
} else if ( is_month() ) {
    $context['title'] = 'Archive: ' . get_the_date( 'M Y' );
} else if ( is_year() ) {
    $context['title'] = 'Archive: ' . get_the_date( 'Y' );
} else if ( is_tag() ) {
    $context['title'] = single_tag_title( '', false );
} else if ( is_category() ) {
    $context['title'] = single_cat_title( '', false );
    array_unshift( $templates, 'archive-' . get_query_var( 'cat' ) . '.twig' );
} else if ( is_post_type_archive() ) {
    $context['title'] = post_type_archive_title( '', false );
    array_unshift( $templates, 'archive-' . get_post_type() . '.twig' );
}

$context['posts'] = new Timber\PostQuery();
Timber::render( $templates, $context );
```

by my understanding, if I navigate to *http://.......com/index.php/category/newcategory/* it should go grab the **archive-newcategory.twig** file, as a template.
Another example, if i go to *http://.......com/index.php/category/anothercat/* it should go grab the **archive-anothercat.twig** . Is it possible that i am understanding something wrong? Because if this is the case, my starter theme does not work as intended.
I can't find a dynamic solution in the docs, if this isn't the one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s working as intended. When `is_category()` is true, the archive will fetch the category ID through `get_query_var( 'cat' )`, and not the category name.

You can update the code in **archive.php** to add the Twig template you’ll want to use. For example:

```
else if ( is_category() ) {
    $term = new Timber\Term( get_queried_object_id() );

    $context['term']  = $term;
    $context['title'] = single_cat_title( '', false );

    array_unshift( $templates, 'archive-' . $term->slug . '.twig' );
}
```

Or you could also use a different PHP template. Consider the [list of PHP templates on wphierarchy.com](http://wphierarchy.com/). There you can see that you could use a **category.php** file in your theme root:

```
$context = Timber::get_context();
$context['title'] = single_cat_title( '', false );

Timber::render( 'archive-category.twig', $context );
```

Comment: For the intended use i prefer the archive.php as the base, instead of category files. I'll check it out once i get the time. :) thanks already! (Making the most of the timber functionalities is my goal)

Comment: I tried your suggestion, however if i got a post category named "featured" and go to .../category/featured it will not pick the archive-featured.twig file. However if i make it categoryid ( archive-1.twig ) that works. But that is not my intent. I want it to be the name of the category.
Please tell me i am missing something essential here.

Comment: Did you leave the existing `else if ( is_category() ) {` in there or did you replace it with my suggestion?

Comment: i left it, so the numbers would stil work. i guess that was the issue. i will try it later. thanks by the way! really appreciate your time 

Comment: replacing the `else if ( is_category() ) {...}`  did the trick! Thanks a lot!